# How to double the intervals in Y-axis while X-axis remains same

Tags: r, excel

I have a data set of a population
I need the y-axis, to double with the following fixed interval:

```
 Y axis: 
 0, 
 250000
 500000
 1000000
 2000000
 4000000
 8000000
 16000000
 32000000
```

Then use the appropriate data.

The data is currently in xls format. Please let me know if this is possible in Excel or R Language? or what is the solution to this. Thanks

I want the above values in the highlighted area in the below image

[image]

Comment: How about converting Y axis to log10 scale?

Comment: I am afraid that only gives me ranges as
1,
10,
100, 1000, 10000 and so on

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Using R ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

#dummy data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = runif(10, 0, 3230000))

#plot
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line() +
  #add manual breaks for Y axis
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = c(0, 25000 * 2^c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure if this is what you want, if not please reformat your question

```
first cell value=0
second cell value=250000
other cell formula=previousCell*2
eg:

    cell a1=0
    cell a2=250000
    cell a3=a2+a2

    copy a3 and paste it to the rest of the cell
```

Comment: These are not data values that I want,

I want to change the values along y axis

Comment: I have edited the original question so that it can be more clear.

Comment: I want the above values as y axis intervals